# Fill up the username or password on website through my android apps

Tags: android

I am android developer. I am making an android application. This application is to store username and password. When we will enter any url then this application helps to retrieve password from database or open the url to android browser.   Please give me some favour of your opinion.. My problem is that when i open url , the password and username not retrieve from database, only url is open.   Please give me suggestion that how i get my username and password from database...fill up the username or password on website automatically...

Comment: Are you sure about your target ? I mean all the browser got this feature already
If you really want to do this, you can dig in the browser code to know how they do (don't reinvent the wheel :))

Comment: @PlumillonForge: Not everybody is comfortable with browsers saving credentials, which motivates the use (and implementation) of password managers!

Answer (score 0):

Filling the username automatically is only possible if the browser supports some extension point. The only browser with plugin support I know of on Android is Dolphin. LastPass comes with such I plugin.

On other browsers, it becomes more difficult. "Safe in Cloud" has an interesting mechanism you might want to look at. And finally, my app "Keepass2Android" uses a workflow described  in https://keepass2android.codeplex.com/documentation. Basically, it is:

- if the user is on a website that needs credentials, he uses "Share URL" from the menu and selects the app
- the app finds the appropriate credentials from the database and makes them accessible. Either through clipboard (which is not particularly safe on Android, see https://www2.dcsec.uni-hannover.de/files/p170.pdf or by implementing a custom Android keyboard. However, this keyboard cannot be opened without user interaction.